# PHP FPM not load changes from php.ini

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

i have strange problem - i'm using PHP 7.4.9 FPM but somehow changes made in php.ini file don't load.

I've checked where is php file with current config using command:

`php --ini`

response was:

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-redis.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini, /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini`

so i've made changes in `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` file and restart php with command

`sudo /etc/init.d/php7.4-fpm restart` and `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`

but changes in file don't load - as i had 2M input file size i still have.

Any ideas?

Comment: CLI and Apache use different php.ini files. Check if you have a folder called `fpm` in your `/etc/php/7.4/` folder. If so, there should be a php.ini file in it as well, which is the one fpm uses.

Answer (score 2):

For me, editing `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini` worked.

To make the changes effective, I ran:

```
systemctl reload php7.4-fpm.service
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the systemctl hint. I inherited a php system, and I didn't know that this is how FPM works.